# Deleteing residue from PDB using Biopython library

Tags: python, biopython, protein-database

Using biopython library, I want to remove the residues that are listed in list as follows. This thread (http://pelican.rsvs.ulaval.ca/mediawiki/index.php/Manipulating_PDB_files_using_BioPython) provides an example to remove residue. I have following code to remove residues

```
 residue_ids_to_remove = [105, 5, 8, 10, 25, 48]
 structure = pdbparser.get_structure("3chy", "./3chy.pdb")
 first_model = structure[0]
 for chain in first_model:
     for residue in chain:
         id = residue.id
         if id[1] in residue_ids_to_remove:
             chain.detach_child(id[1])
 modified_first_model = first_model
```

But this code did not work and raised the error

```
def detach_child(self, id):
    "Remove a child."
    child=self.child_dict[id]
    KeyError: '105'
```

What's wrong with this code?

Alternatively, I can do using accept_residue() and write it in PDB. I don't want to follow like this becauseI want to do it while in memory for further processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Biopython cannot find the key in the inner dictionary to the chain, because you're supplying a random key. The dict looks like this:

```
child_dict = {(' ', 5, ' '): <Residue HOH het=W resseq=5 icode= >,
              (' ', 6, ' '): <Residue HOH het=W resseq=6 icode= >,
              (' ', 7, ' '): <Residue HOH het=W resseq=7 icode= >}
```

That is: using tuples as dict keys. You can see the dict doing `print chain.child_dict`.

Once you know this, the error/solution is clear. Pass a valid key to `detach_child`, namely remove the `[1]`:

```
   if id[1] in residue_ids_to_remove:
       chain.detach_child(id)
```

### The right way

Detach the children from the chain level, and do not cycle the residues directly:

```
for chain in first model:
    for id in residue_ids_to_remove:
        chain.detach_child((' ', id, ' '))
```

Or with list comprehension:

```
for chain in first_model:
    [chain.detach_child((' ', id, ' ')) for id in residue_ids_to_remove]
```

Comment: thanks!!! Still, it is not working perfectly. When "chain.detach_child(id)" is executed. It removes one residue belongs to id and skips next residue that is subsequent residue. I am wondering why it does like this?

Comment: I don't understand the situation. If you `detach_child((' ', 5, ' ')`, what is skipped? What you consider "next" in a dictionary? `(' ', 6, ' ')` maybe?

Comment: Yeah...  more detail - when chain.detach_child((' ', 5, ' ')) was executed, it skipped     (' ', 6, ' ') . I don't know the reason. To see the effect, I just commented      # chain.detach_child((' ', 5, ' ')) and it showed all residue.id like (' ', 5, ' ') , (' ', 6, ' '). From this, I found the error is in chain.detach_child((' ', 5, ' ')) but I don't have an idea how to solve it.

Comment: I found it. when looping the list AND altering it, the adjacent residues are "jumped" in the list. You have to cycle a copy of the list: `for residue in list(chain):` instead of `for residue in chain:`

Comment: It works, but I think it's wrong! Inserting the "correct" path in the original answer.